# How to make Combobox multiple selection but only store it? Here's a code can somebody make it short?

Tags: java

I'm making a horoscope program and I wanted the user to select a date, and store it to some zodiac sign like Aquarius. Aquarius dates are Jan 20 - Feb 18. How do I make this code short?

I tried using multiple `if` statements, and it works, but I wanted this to be short, using only one `if..else` statement:

```
        if (ZodiacMonth.equals("January") && (ZodiacDay.equals("20"))) {
            this.dispose();
            Aquarius obj = new Aquarius();
            obj.setVisible(true);
}                                        
    if (ZodiacMonth.equals("January") && (ZodiacDay.equals("21" ))) {
            this.dispose();
            Aquarius obj = new Aquarius();
            obj.setVisible(true);
}
    if (ZodiacMonth.equals("January") && (ZodiacDay.equals("22" ))) {
            this.dispose();
            Aquarius obj = new Aquarius();
            obj.setVisible(true);
}
    if (ZodiacMonth.equals("January") && (ZodiacDay.equals("23" ))) {
            this.dispose();
            Aquarius obj = new Aquarius();
            obj.setVisible(true);
}
    if (ZodiacMonth.equals("January") && (ZodiacDay.equals("24" ))) {
            this.dispose();
            Aquarius obj = new Aquarius();
            obj.setVisible(true);
}
    if (ZodiacMonth.equals("January") && (ZodiacDay.equals("25" ))) {
            this.dispose();
            Aquarius obj = new Aquarius();
            obj.setVisible(true);
}
    if (ZodiacMonth.equals("January") && (ZodiacDay.equals("26" ))) {
            this.dispose();
            Aquarius obj = new Aquarius();
            obj.setVisible(true);
}
    if (ZodiacMonth.equals("January") && (ZodiacDay.equals("27" ))) {
            this.dispose();
            Aquarius obj = new Aquarius();
            obj.setVisible(true);
}
    if (ZodiacMonth.equals("January") && (ZodiacDay.equals("28" ))) {
            this.dispose();
            Aquarius obj = new Aquarius();
            obj.setVisible(true);
}
    if (ZodiacMonth.equals("January") && (ZodiacDay.equals("29" ))) {
            this.dispose();
            Aquarius obj = new Aquarius();
            obj.setVisible(true);
}
    if (ZodiacMonth.equals("January") && (ZodiacDay.equals("30" ))) {
            this.dispose();
            Aquarius obj = new Aquarius();
            obj.setVisible(true);
}
    if (ZodiacMonth.equals("January") && (ZodiacDay.equals("31" ))) {
            this.dispose();
            Aquarius obj = new Aquarius();
            obj.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Object ZodiacMonth =jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();
Object ZodiacDay =jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();

I use combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the number string to an integer and you can use numeric comparison.  Giving ...

```
int day = Integer.parseInt(zodiacDay);  // throws an unchecked exception
                                        // if 'zodiacDay' is not a valid
                                        // integer representation.
if (zodiacMonth.equals("January") && day >= 20 && day <= 26) {
    this.dispose();
    new Aquarius().setVisible(true);
}
```